# Define a subdirectory for a jekyll collection

Tags: jekyll

How can I have my collection's files under `_stuff/data/{a,b,c}.md` but the permalinks be `stuff/{a,b,c}/`?

Background: I want to move the data folder to its own repo. It's currently called "stuff" but in the new repo I want to have `Readme.md` and other files in the main directory, with the "stuff" moved into a "data" folder. With that repo as a git submodule I would thus have this annoying `stuff/data` which should not bleed into the permalinks. I also want to have only the `_stuff/data` folder in my collection and not the whole `_stuff` folder.

ChatGPT got me half way to my goal. It suggested to set this configuration

```
collections:
  stuff:
    output: true
    directory: _stuff/data
    permalink: /stuff/:title/
```

and I do not quite understand why `:title` resolves to the filename without the `.md` even though my files have `title: ...` in their frontmatters.

What is missing: I want to exclude files directly under `_stuff` or in other folders under `_stuff`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override `slug` in your front matter to change `:title`. I'm guessing this is because `title` generally contains capital letters and spaces - not things you want in a URL.

Here's `:title` from https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

> Title from the document’s filename. May be overridden via the document’s `slug` front matter. Preserves case from the source.

---

Jekyll has a convention for where collection files are stored, rather than allowing/requiring you to configure where they are. I don't think you'll be able to filter those files out where they are easily, or specify a different subfolder for that one collection.

The easiest solution here would be to move/copy the files to where Jekyll needs them. You could do this many different ways, but here's a bash script to demonstrate - instead of running `bundle exec jekyll build`, you'd run `./bin/build`:

`bin/build`:

```
#!bin/bash

cp -R _stuff/data _data
bundle exec jekyll build
```

If you *(or ChatGPT)* are familiar with Ruby, another solution could be to write a Jekyll plugin to read those files. I'd suggest a [generator plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators/) that reads the files from disk from where they are in your repo, then parse and add those manually to Jekyll's `site.data`.

Comment: The comment on `:title` / `slug:` is interesting but not helping with the other question. Using exclude: _stuff, include: _stuff/data in the config I thought could work but didn't. So I feel like my remaining question has no real/nice answer.

Comment: The second part of the answer covers it. As far as I know, Jekyll does not have a configuration option that fits your specific requirements so you'll need to workaround it by moving those files, or parsing them separately.